# Add signature to pdf file in asp.net

Tags: asp.net, vb.net, abcpdf

I have below code which generates pdf file. Now I want to add user's digital signature on this pdf file.

How can I able to do that?

I have used ABCPdf component to generate pdf files.

```
Dim theDoc As Doc = New Doc()
theDoc.HtmlOptions.Timeout = 300000
theDoc.HtmlOptions.ImageQuality = 101
'total w=612 h=792
theDoc.Rect.Position(50, 70)
theDoc.Rect.Width = 532
theDoc.Rect.Height = 610
Dim theid As Integer = theDoc.AddImageUrl("http://google.com")
While theDoc.Chainable(theid)
    theDoc.Page = theDoc.AddPage()
    theid = theDoc.AddImageToChain(theid)
End While

theDoc.Save(System.Web.HttpContext.Current.Server.MapPath("/1.pdf"))
theDoc.Clear()
```

Comment: http://www.websupergoo.com/helppdfnet/source/6-abcpdf.objects/signature/1-methods/sign.htm   and http://www.websupergoo.com/helppdfnet/source/4-examples/18-annotations.htm